# Print all prime numbers to <stdout> within the threshold boundaries with the range provided by user

Tags: beginner, c, primes

I found this exercise on the web and this is my attempt to solve it.

Things i'm interested the most from this coding review

- Naming convention
- I don't comment the code that much. For you to faster review the code i did
  extra commenting.Should i comment the code this way ?
- Your professional opinion
- Things a i can use to improve this code, therefore my programming skills.

**getprimes.h / getprimes.c**

```
#ifndef GETPRIMES_H_
#define GETPRIMES_H_

void print_primes( int iter, const int max );

#endif
```

---

```
static int is_num_prime( const int n )
{ 
    // First prime number is 2 
    if ( n < 2 ) return 0;

    for( int i = 2; i < n; ++i )
        /*If this holds true for any iteration of the loop
          number is not prime and exit the function with status(0)*/
        if( n % i == 0 && i != n )
            return 0;

    /*Number(n) is prime if all if checks are false,
      therfore return(1) when loop ends.*/
    return 1;
}

void print_primes( int iter, const int max )
{

    int prime_count = 0;
    int line_break  = prime_count + 10;

    puts("");
    // min, max range provided by user. iter = min.
    for(; iter <= max; ++iter ){
        /*If the number is prime, print it and increase
          the prime_count by one */
        if( is_num_prime(iter) ){
            printf("| %-4i | ", iter);
            prime_count++;

            // Add the line break after 10 prints of prime numbers.
            if( prime_count == line_break ){
                line_break = prime_count + 10;
                puts("");
            }
        }
    }   
    // Print the total prime numbers count.
    printf("\n\n[ Prime numbers Count:%i ]\n\n", 
        prime_count );
}
```

---

**str2int.h / str2int.c**

```
#ifndef STR2INT_H_
#define STR2INT_H_

long str_to_int( const char arr[] );

#endif
```

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

static int is_str_digit( const char arr[] )
{ // Check if each character of an array is a digit.
    int iter = 0;

    /*Iterate over an array while array[iter] character is not
      a new line or null character.
      - If array[iter] character is not a digit return(0)
      - If the loop did all iterations then all array[iter] characters are
        digits, therfore return (1).*/
    while( arr[iter] != '\n' && arr[iter] != '\0' ){
        if( !isdigit(arr[iter]) )
            return 0;
        iter++;
    }
    return 1;
}

long str_to_int( const char arr[] )
{ /* If array is not NULL, and all array characters are digits:
     - Convert the characters of the array to a long int.
     - Return the result of conversion.
     Return (0) in any other case.   */
    long result;

    if( arr != NULL && is_str_digit( arr )){
        result = strtol( arr, NULL, 10 );
        if( result )
            return result;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include "str2int.h"
#include "getprimes.h"

#define LEN(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof(*x))

const typedef struct {
    const long min;
    const long max;
}Threshold;

typedef struct {
    char str[10];
    long min;
    long max;
}UserInput;

int main()
{
    /*Threshold range. Range provided by user 
      cannot exceed threshold range boundaries */
    Threshold range = { 2, 10000 };

    /*This is a variable of type UserInput that will
      store user input strings and their conversions to long int*/
    UserInput input;

    /*Get the first user input range boundary(min) */
    printf("Search for prime numbers [FROM]:");
    fgets( input.str, LEN(input.str),stdin );   

    // Convert it to ( long int )
    input.min = str_to_int( input.str );    

    /* If the conversion is unsuccessful input.min will be 0,
       so this check if conversion is successful and if first user input
       is within the threshold range boundaries.*/ 
    if( input.min >= range.min && input.min <= range.max ){

        /*Get the second user input range boundary(max) */
        printf("Search for prime numbers [TO  ]:");
        fgets( input.str, LEN(input.str),stdin );   

        // Convert it to (long int)
        input.max = str_to_int( input.str );    

        /*This check is conversion is successful and if input.max is 
          within the range( input.min - range.max )*/
        if ( input.max > input.min && input.max < range.max )
            // Print all prime numbers within the provided range.
            print_primes( input.min, input.max );
        else
            puts("[QUITING] Not acceptable input");

    }else
        puts("[QUITING] Not acceptable input");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

### Prime number efficiency.

There are multitudes of ways to improve the prime test.  OP's code is a basic one and works for all `n`.  Good step 1.  Let us try more

Why the `i != n` test.  `i < n` takes care of that

```
for( int i = 2; i < n; ++i )
    // if( n % i == 0 && i != n ) return 0;
    if(n % i == 0) return 0;
```

Further improvements maintain prime lists (not shown) and use of the quick sieve of [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) - practical when `O(n)` bits of memory are available.

Many compilers when performing `n % i` can calculate `n / i` for little or no extra emitted code.  Source code can use the quotient to stop the loop *far* sooner: about `√n` iterations rather than `n`.  This is better in many cases that than iterating to `sqrt(n)` (using the `math.h` function) as that invokes floating-point math with its rounding issues and potential less precision that the chosen integer type.

```
int quot = 2;
for( int i = 2; i <= quot; ++i )
    if (n % i == 0) return 0;
    quot = n/i;
}
```

---

### Choose a consistent integer type

`print_primes( input.min, input.max );` down converts `long`  to `int`. If the prime test is for `int`s. I'd expect consistency.  `input.min, input.max` should be the same type.  As this is a prime test and no need for negative numbers, consider `unsigned` or go for widest like `uintmax_t`.

---

### Minor

Simplify digit string detection.
`'\n'` and `'\0'` are not digits either, so exit loop when a non-digit is found.  Note: `isdigit(ch)` is UB when `ch < 0` and not `EOF`,  so a cast is used below.
Not shown: recommend to lop off the `'\n'` in the calling code and only allow a `'\0'` ending here.

```
static int is_str_digit(const char arr[]) {
   size_t i = 0;
   while  (isdigit((unsigned char) arr[i])) {
     i++;
   }
   return (i>0) && ((arr[i] == '\n') || (arr[i] == '\0'));
}
```

---

6.1 or 1/2 dozen of the other (not too much difference) idea:
`long str_to_int( const char arr[] )` could form the `long` instead of calling a loop that checks each digit and then calls `strtol()`.  Note that `str_to_int()` sounds like it converts a string to an `int` rather than `long`.  Consider renaming to `str_to_long()`.

```
#include <limits.h>
long str_to_long(const char *arr) {
  long sum = 0;
  while (isdigit((unsigned char) *arr)) {
    if ((sum >= LONG_MAX/10) && (sum > LONG_MAX/10 || *arr > LONG_MAX%10 + '0')) {         
      // overflow
      return INT_MAX;
    }
    sum = sum*10 + *arr++ - '0';
  }
  return sum;
}
```

---

I/O details

`stdout` should be *flushed* to insure it appears before the requested input via `fgets().  Robust code checks the return value of`fgets`.

```
printf("Search for prime numbers [FROM]:");`
fflush(stdout);

if (fgets( input.str, LEN(input.str),stdin ) == NULL) {
  Handle_EOF_or_Error();
}
```

---

Printing the line break;
Rather than maintain `line_break`, simply use `%10`

```
         if (prime_count % 10 == 0) puts("");
```

Just before printing the total prime numbers count, test `prime_count` for a consistent output.

```
     if (prime_count % 10) puts("");
```